# Required field after checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with checkboxes that opens a sublist of checkboxes once its clicked.

Say for example, if you select on the checkbox "AntimicrobialProphylaxis"...it drops a sublist of checkboxes with 4 other options. How can I make the sublist become required?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#AntimicrobialProphylaxis").change(function() {
    var showOrHide = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#AntimicrobialProphylaxisSub").toggle(showOrHide);
    $('[name="description"]').toggleClass('required', showOrHide);
  });

  $("#SkinPreparation").change(function() {
    var showOrHide = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#SkinPreparationSub").toggle(showOrHide);
    $('[name="description"]').toggleClass('required', showOrHide);
  });

  $("#HairRemoval").change(function() {
    var showOrHide = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#HairRemovalSub").toggle(showOrHide);
    $('[name="description"]').toggleClass('required', showOrHide);
  });

  $("#AutologousPlateletRichPlasmaApplication").change(function() {
    var showOrHide = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#AutologousPlateletRichPlasmaApplicationSub").toggle(showOrHide);
    $('[name="description"]').toggleClass('required', showOrHide);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3 class="QOE1">Quality of Evidence I</h3>
  <input id="AntimicrobialProphylaxis" name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" />Antimicrobial Prophylaxis
  <br />

  <span id="AntimicrobialProphylaxisSub" style="display:none;">
       <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" class="" /> Cefazolin<br />
       <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" class="" /> Vancomycin<br />
       <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" class="" /> Gentamicin<br />
        <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" class="" /> Other<br />
        <textarea name="description" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea><br />
        </span>

  <input id="SkinPreparation" name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" />Skin Preparation
  <br />

  <span id="SkinPreparationSub" style="display:none;">
         <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            <span>Aqueous/alcohol based</span>

  <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" /><span>Other</span>
  <br />
  <textarea name="description" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
  <br />
  </span>

  <input id="SkinPreparation" name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" />Surgical Hand Antisepsis
  <br />

  <input id="SkinPreparation" name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" />Parenteral Nutrition Timing
  <br />
</div>
```

The code allows the sublist to appear but I was unable to make it required. I have tried using .prop from jQuery and the required html attribute.

Comment: Have you tried writing your own javascript to force users to check one of them? The idea is if `AntimicrobialProphylaxis` is checked, at least one check box in `AntimicrobialProphylaxisSub` must be checked.

Comment: this is what I had in mind...(sry for mess) 'code' $("#AntimicrobialProphylaxis").change(function () {
      if($(this).is(':checked') {
          $(".Other || .Vancomycin || .Gentamicin || .Other").attr('required');
      } else {
          $(".Other || .Vancomycin || .Gentamicin || .Other").removeAttr('required');
      }
  });

Comment: What is your expected behaviors? You make the sub-list required, and then? You don't want to submit the form if users don't check the sub-list?

Comment: if you check AntimicrobialProphylaxis, you must also check at least one of the other fields in order to submit the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you are looking to make sure at least one item is checked but there can be more than one you need to make sure one for each group is checked before the form is submitted. Once one is checked you need to remove the required attribute from the other check boxes else they are ALL required for the form to be submitted.

You could try something like this:

```
  $("#AntimicrobialProphylaxis").change(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      var showOrHide = $this.is(":checked");
      $("#" + this.id + "Sub").toggle(showOrHide);

      var requiredChecks = $("[data-toggle-target=" + this.id + "]").children("[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', false);

      requiredChecks.attr('required', showOrHide).click(function () {

          if ($('[name=' + this.name + ']:checked').length == 0) {
              $('[name=' + this.name + ']').attr('required ', true);
          } else {
              $('[name=' + this.name + ']').attr('required', false);
          }

      });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7a12gb1p/

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment:

> if you check AntimicrobialProphylaxis, you must also check at least
>   one of the other fields in order to submit the form

Here is how you can validate form fields using jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form-submit").click(function(event) {
    var error = false;
    if ($('#AntimicrobialProphylaxis').is(':checked') && $('#AntimicrobialProphylaxisSub input:checked').length == 0) error = true;
    if ($('#SkinPreparation').is(':checked') && $('#SkinPreparationSub input:checked').length == 0) error = true;
    if (error) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert('Error! Please check your form!');
    } else alert('No errors! Form will be submitted.');
  });

  $("#AntimicrobialProphylaxis").change(function() {
    var showOrHide = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#AntimicrobialProphylaxisSub").toggle(showOrHide);
    $('[name="description"]').toggleClass('required', showOrHide);
  });

  $("#SkinPreparation").change(function() {
    var showOrHide = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#SkinPreparationSub").toggle(showOrHide);
    $('[name="description"]').toggleClass('required', showOrHide);
  });

  $("#HairRemoval").change(function() {
    var showOrHide = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#HairRemovalSub").toggle(showOrHide);
    $('[name="description"]').toggleClass('required', showOrHide);
  });

  $("#AutologousPlateletRichPlasmaApplication").change(function() {
    var showOrHide = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#AutologousPlateletRichPlasmaApplicationSub").toggle(showOrHide);
    $('[name="description"]').toggleClass('required', showOrHide);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3 class="QOE1">Quality of Evidence I</h3>
  <form id="my-form" method="post" action="">
    <input id="AntimicrobialProphylaxis" name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" />Antimicrobial Prophylaxis
    <br />

    <span id="AntimicrobialProphylaxisSub" style="display:none;">
       <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" class="" /> Cefazolin<br />
       <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" class="" /> Vancomycin<br />
       <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" class="" /> Gentamicin<br />
       <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" class="" /> Other<br />
       <textarea name="description" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea><br />
    </span>

    <input id="SkinPreparation" name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" />Skin Preparation
    <br />

    <span id="SkinPreparationSub" style="display:none;">
        <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        <span>Aqueous/alcohol based</span>

    <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" /><span>Other</span>
    <br />
    <textarea name="description" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
    <br />
    </span>

    <input id="SkinPreparation" name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" />Surgical Hand Antisepsis
    <br />

    <input id="SkinPreparation" name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" />Parenteral Nutrition Timing
    <br />
    <!-- Submit Button -->

    <button id="form-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

You can also add the HTML input [`required`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) attribute with `$('[name="description"]').prop('required', true);`.

In your case:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#AntimicrobialProphylaxis").change(function() {
    var showOrHide = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#AntimicrobialProphylaxisSub").toggle(showOrHide);
    $('[name="description"]').prop('required', showOrHide);
    $('#AntimicrobialProphylaxisSub > input').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('required', showOrHide);
    });
  });

  $("#SkinPreparation").change(function() {
    var showOrHide = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#SkinPreparationSub").toggle(showOrHide);
    $('[name="description"]').prop('required', showOrHide);
    $('#SkinPreparationSub > input').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('required', showOrHide);
    });
  });

  $("#HairRemoval").change(function() {
    var showOrHide = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#HairRemovalSub").toggle(showOrHide);
    $('[name="description"]').prop('required', showOrHide);
  });

  $("#AutologousPlateletRichPlasmaApplication").change(function() {
    var showOrHide = $(this).is(':checked');
    $("#AutologousPlateletRichPlasmaApplicationSub").toggle(showOrHide);
    $('[name="description"]').prop('required', showOrHide);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3 class="QOE1">Quality of Evidence I</h3>
  <input id="AntimicrobialProphylaxis" name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" />Antimicrobial Prophylaxis
  <br />

  <span id="AntimicrobialProphylaxisSub" style="display:none;">
       <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" class="" /> Cefazolin<br />
       <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" class="" /> Vancomycin<br />
       <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" class="" /> Gentamicin<br />
       <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" class="" /> Other<br />
       <textarea name="description" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea><br />
    </span>

  <input id="SkinPreparation" name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" />Skin Preparation
  <br />

  <span id="SkinPreparationSub" style="display:none;">
        <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        <span>Aqueous/alcohol based</span>

  <input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" /><span>Other</span>
  <br />
  <textarea name="description" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
  <br />
  </span>

  <input id="SkinPreparation" name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" />Surgical Hand Antisepsis
  <br />

  <input id="SkinPreparation" name="selection" type="checkbox" value="1" />Parenteral Nutrition Timing
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: that is what I had in mind, but it the required field doesn't appear and I can just bypass it. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. If you want to add the `required` attribute to `checkbox` as well as to `textarea` elements, then the code above will work.

Answer (score 1):

> if you check AntimicrobialProphylaxis, you must also check at least
>   one of the other fields in order to submit the form

Base on what you need, I think you should write a function like this to validate your input:

```
function isValidated() {
    var isValid = true;
    var isChecked = $("#AntimicrobialProphylaxis").is(":checked");
    if (isChecked) {
        isValid = false;
        var isSubChecked = $('#AntimicrobialProphylaxisSub > input:checked').length > 0;
        if (isSubChecked) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

The function above forces users to check at least 1 check box in sub-list if they checked the `AntimicrobialProphylaxis`. Look at full code at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d013z7oa/).